# Spring Kafka cannot find Kafka Properties Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to use Spring Kafka in my project where is spring boot version is 2.2.2.RELEASE, kafka version is 2.3.x.

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
```

I have my KafkaConfig class and Listener Class setup:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {
Config cfg = new Config();


@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(
    ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
    cfg.getProperty("server"));
props.put(
    ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
    UUID.randomUUID());
props.put(
    ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
    StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(
    ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
    StringDeserializer.class);
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
return factory;
}
}
```

KafkaConsumer.java

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {
private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
  .getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

@KafkaListener(topics = "anomaly-topic")
void listener(String message) {
LOG.info("Listener [{}]", message);
}
}
```

When i am trying to run my application, i am getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.kafka-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/requests/IsolationLevel
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to this is to disable KafkaAutoConfiguration.class,

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same happen to me, the reason was because I had the following library:

```
implementation(group="io.confluent", name="kafka-avro-serializer", version="5.5.1")
```

Which comes with its own `kafka-clients` with version `5.5.1-ccs` which was being picked up and causing compatibility issues.

I solved this by using [Spring Dependency Management](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/):

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
}
```

Then running a `gradle clean`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yayotron, in my case I had to disable KafkaConfiguration class. Thanks for answering, Have a nice day.